# Is there a way to move a function into a given point?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, functions

Given a function $f(x)$ and given a certain point $x = (x_1, x_2)$.
Without knowing any characteristics of the function and how the point is located in relationship to the function, is there a way to shift $f(x)$, such that it lies on the curve?

I know the simple transformations and shifts e.g. $f(x) + a$ or $f(x+b)$. Im not looking for a transformation of the kind $c \cdot f(x)$.

Concretely, my function is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Given a point, e.g. $x = (10000, 0.2)$, I want to shift $f$, such that $x$ lies on the curve.

Im not even sure if this is possible. Is there even a way for this?

Comment: Let’s say you want it to go through $a,b$. Then, consider $g(x)=b-f(a)+f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lift $f$ vertically, $$g(x):=f(x)-f(x_1)+x_2.$$

---

You can also translate horizontally,

$$g(x):=f(x-a)$$ by solving for $a$ in

$$f(x_1-a)=x_2$$ ($a=x_1-f^{-1}(x_2)$ if $f$ is invertible).

---

The first solution is always feasible, not the second.

---

Yet another option is to pick a point on the curve, say $(x_3,x_4=f(x_3))$ and translate obliquely,

$$g(x)=f(x+x_3-x_1)+x_2-x_4.$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto f(x) - f(x_1) + x_2$ has the property that it maps $x_1$ to $f(x_1)-f(x_1)+x_2$. Is this what you need?